# impdp doesn't import table data when using exclude parameter

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, impdp

I want to import a DB dump using below command, which will import all the data, but excluding the index and disabling the constraints

```
impdp FERROVIAL/F3RR0V1AL@FERROVIAL PARFILE=params.par
```

with the params file containing this params:

```
DIRECTORY=DB_EXPDP
DUMPFILE=FERROVIAL.DMP
LOGFILE=FERROVIAL.log
REUSE_DATAFILES=YES
EXCLUDE=REF_CONSTRAINT
EXCLUDE=CONSTRAINT
EXCLUDE=table:"='CONTRATOS'"
EXCLUDE procedure, function, package
EXCLUDE=index
```

But the tables are created but without any data

Comment: do you have data in your dump ?

Comment: yes, I did it before some test without any exclude and I got all data

Comment: I believe `CONTRATOS` is your table name, which you wanted to exclude . right ?

Comment: yes, is a table I want to exclude and it has not been created.. that's OK

Comment: retry by removing `EXCLUDE=REF_CONSTRAINT 
 EXCLUDE=CONSTRAINT` part

Comment: @enLopes can you atleast let us know, if any of the suggestion works ?? So that, people who get same issue should know the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you have specified parameter `REUSE_DATAFILES` as `YES`, then the existing data files would be reinitialized.

So, you need to set **[`REUSE_DATAFILES = NO`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-5842DA01-AE79-4205-9FBA-9F65A9C61F3C.htm#SUTIL930)** or remove this parameter as default value is `NO`

> REUSE_DATAFILES=YES may result in a loss of data.